# Correlation: If $Z^2$s are correlated, it doesnt imply that $Z$s are correlated?

Tags: correlation

I read in my lecture slide that if $Z^2$s are correlated, it doesn't imply that $Z$s are correlated, but I don't understand it. Any example will be  welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

- $X$ be a standard normal random variable with distribution $\mathcal N(0,1)$,
- $Y$ be independently another standard normal random variable and
- $Z=\text{sign}(Y) \, |X|$, also a standard normal random variable

Then $X^2=Z^2$, so with correlation of $1$ between them, but $X$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated with correlation of $0$ between them (though they are not independent since $|X|=|Z|$)

while $Y^2$ and $Z^2$ are independent, so uncorrelated with correlation of $0$ between them, but $Y$ and $Z$ are correlated with correlation of $\frac{2}{\pi} \approx 0.6366$ between them

Comment: thanks! is the opposite also true? If X and Z are correlated, then $X^2$ and $Z^2$ may not be correlated

Comment: @ELI - Yes - I have added an example in the opposite direction